# How will i make this table in latex?

Tags: tables

[image]

everytime i try the table goes out of the page.

Comment: please show a small complete document that shows your current code

Comment: You could use tabularx

Comment: You are most likely using `l`eft-aligned columns in your column specification for the table. `l`-columns don't wrap. For that you'd need a `p{<len>}` column, or perhaps a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment seems more appropriate in your case; that is the second case discussed in [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332903/5764) (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

As skeleton for your table. Real text in cells you should write yourself (with it replace `\lipsum*[66]` which generate dummy text):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] % <---
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
1   &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    \\
    \hline
2   &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have more vertical space above/below in table cells, then you can do this by help of `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
1   &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    \\
    \hline
2   &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    &   \lipsum*[66]    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok but how will i edit the text in between and i need 5 columns u have only three??

Comment: @RåhülRàvi, in place where is now `\lipsum*[66]` you should write your text. See edited answer.

Comment: thankyou ! it worked out but the table is aligned to bottom of the page. i want to make it to the top ?

Comment: @RåhülRàvi, I didn't  add table placement (now is added: `\begin{table}[ht]`). I suggest you to read some introductory text about table and float environments, for example: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020 respectively

Comment: whatever value of height i gave it is coming in the next page. could you specify the [ht] value so the table comes below LITERATURE SURVEY heading?

Comment: @RåhülRàvi, I'm very sorry, I don't understood what is your problem (my cristal ball is broken :-( ). I suggest you to edit your question and add missed information in form of small but complete document (for example based on on my answer) or better ask new question in which you should provide all relevant information. Preparing it, please read introductory text about tables for which I give you line in previous comment. Now I can only guess, that you actually look for table which can span over multiple page.